# Does LAZY fetch type produce N +1 select

Tags: hibernate, fetch, openjpa, eager-loading

After reading this article [enter link description here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-identify-and-resilve-n1)

I got the idea that a fetch mode = LAZY will always result in N +1 problem. IS this true? If so ,why? OpenJPA/Hibernate should be able to optimize the query even if fetch type is LAZY. No?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify  eager fetch in query to avoid it. This produces a JOIN sql.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Entity1.class);
c.setFetchMode("anotherObj", FetchMode.JOIN)
return c.list();
```

Comment: My question is not how to avoid N +! by an eager fetch, but...does a LAZY fetch automatically mean a N +1 select?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. But the extra SELECTs are executed only when you access the objects defined in a relationship (that's why it is called LAZY load).

This is an excellent article that explains it in more details: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

Cheers